# Roku device not responding to ping

Tags: makefile, roku

I have created a simple 'hello world' style Roku app and it builds and installs just fine. However, when I try to view the channel, it does not invoke the screen I've set after splash, and when I try to run `make run` or `make install` I always get `ERROR: Device not responding to ping.`

Looking at the makefile, I think this is the error:

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CHECK_ROKU_DEV_TARGET is used to check if ROKU_DEV_TARGET refers a
# Roku device on the network that has an enabled developer web server.
# If the target doesn't exist or doesn't have an enabled web server
# the connection should fail.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
define CHECK_ROKU_DEV_TARGET
    if [ -z "$(ROKU_DEV_TARGET)" ]; then \
        echo "ERROR: ROKU_DEV_TARGET is not set."; \
        exit 1; \
    fi
    echo "Checking dev server at $(ROKU_DEV_TARGET)..."

    # first check if the device is on the network via a quick ping
    ping $(QUICK_PING_ARGS) $(ROKU_DEV_TARGET) &> $(DEV_SERVER_TMP_FILE) || \
        ( \
            echo "ERROR: Device is not responding to ping."; \
            exit 1 \
        )
```

I should note that I *have* set the ROKU_DEV_TARGET and it *is* available via echo. I can also connect to the device using the IP that returns. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Does `ping <roku_ip_address>` from terminal work?

Comment: It does. I can also view from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Roku devices get stuck in a weird state when there are pending updates. You can try going to settings and choosing to check for updates, and then reboot the device.

Comment: I'll check that out. Though I'm almost positive I did check for updates. Doesn't hurt to try again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There also could be cases when after checking for updates it says it's up to date but the device still doesn't respond. Usually, reboot helps.